# Android get system keyboard state

Tags: android, service, input, keyboard, detection

I've seen few question similar but none like what I'm looking for.

The situation is:

I have my own device (so it's root and I have totally access) and I want to control the keyboard (soft). I'm trying to look if there is any event in the kernel or Android has any system to get it. But right now I could not figure it out.

Anyone has a way to do this. So I will be able to know when a keyboard is displayed and when is hide.

I've seen that there are several permissions, like:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_TEXT_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE"/>
```

That may be useful to know that there is something controlling the inputtext or system view.

I'm quite stuck in this, but this should be possible somehow.
Thank you.

Comment: so what do you want to do? You want to check whether keyboard is hidden or visible in your activity or anything else?

Comment: yes but not in my activity, I know how to do that. The thing is this will be a system service. So there won't be a view, an furthermore I want to know when the keyboard is displayed, no matters in which view I am